# which one is correct sentence.

Tags: grammar

neglecting to fix your roof will make it crack and leak.

neglecting to fix your roof will make it cracks and leaks.

neglecting to fix your roof will make it to crack and leak.

im having trouble knowing which one is the correct one focusing on the words crack/cracks and leak/leaks. thank you

Comment: This question should be on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: Causative 'make' once accepted the to-infinitive, as seen in [Typographical Antiquities by Joseph Ames](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2LywBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=%22maketh+him+to%22&source=bl&ots=8TQpN34izT&sig=Hc0b08It83kfVoVnwg29ALvV410&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2nNuYwbTVAhUkDMAKHX8QCTsQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22maketh%20him%20to%22&f=false), but nowadays only takes the bare infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

Causative *make* takes **unmarked** or **bare** infinitival complements: complements headed by an infinitive verb without a *to* marker:

> The Devil made me **do** it.
>   I can't make this program **work**.
>   Neglecting to fix your roof will make it **crack** and **leak**.

Comment: But _cause_ takes the infinitive with _to_: "The Devil caused me to do it". There is no rule to explain this: it is just a property of the words _make_ and _cause_.